# Permutations of Characters

Tags: permutations

How many strings of five characters use the letters a, b, c, d and do not have the letters bad appearing consecutively and in this order? (Letters can occur any number of times, including not at all.)

Comment: Hint: abad, bbad, cbad, dbad, bada, badb, badc, badd

Comment: @Theo what are you doing? huh?

Comment: @ADG Oh, I'm sorry, these are all the bad 4-character strings... Well, you get the idea for five as well... Then subtract those from the $4^5$ possible strings and you are set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total $= 4^5$
Strings containing bad $\newcommand{\1}[2]{{}^{#1}{\mathbb C}_{#2}}= \1314^2$
Subtract those.

Comment: The strings you eliminated have length $6$.  They should have length $5$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig corrected.